# UR5+velocity control: runaway robot after getting closer to goal pose

Tags: python, kinect, object-recognition, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my algorithm, the robot seemingly moves towards the right position, as the joint velocities reduce, after that the velocities start increasing as the robot moves away. I cannot understand why this is happening and need some urgent help. My github project link is given below:
https://github.com/RiddhimanRaut/Ur5_Visual_Servoing
The object recognition and everything else is working as expected. Also the robot does not stop when I stop the run_ur5.py code, I've checked rostopic echo and joint velocities are still being published. Maybe the two problems are related. Please help.

The codes are all mine.

#EDIT 2:
This is a trial velocity publisher I've written just to test the lag issue

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from ur5_control_nodes.msg import floatList

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('ur5_joint_velocities', floatList, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        vels=[0,0,0.05,0,0,0]
    
        pub.publish(vels)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    talker()
```

#Code for color detection

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from ur5_control_nodes.msg import floatList
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import imutils

bridge=CvBridge()
rgb_img=np.zeros((480,640,3),np.uint8)
depth_img=np.zeros((480,640))

#RGB Image Callback
def rgb_callback(rgb_msg):
    global rgb_img   
    rgb_img=bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb_msg, "bgr8")     


#Depth Image Callback 
def d_callback(msg):
    
    global depth_img
    depth_img=bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding="passthrough")
    
    
    
    
#Getting XY Points
def xy_points(frame):
    fl=531.15
    
    xypoints=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=np.int64)

    
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
   
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   
    #defining the Range of Blue color
    blue_lower=np.array([87,100,150],np.uint8)
    blue_upper=np.array([110,255,255],np.uint8)
  
    
    
    blue=cv2.inRange(hsv,blue_lower,blue_upper)
    blue = cv2.erode(blue, None, iterations=2)
    blue = cv2.dilate(blue, None, iterations=2)
    
    cnts_b = cv2.findContours(blue.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts_b = imutils.grab_contours(cnts_b)
    center_b = None
    if len(cnts_b) > 0:
        c_b = max(cnts_b, key=cv2.contourArea)
        # epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c,True)
        # approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,epsilon,True)
        M_b= cv2.moments(c_b)
        center_b= (int(M_b["m10"] / M_b["m00"]), int(M_b["m01"] / M_b["m00"]))
        cv2.circle(frame, center_b, 5, (255, 255,255), -1)
        xypoints[2]=center_b[0]
        xypoints[3]=center_b[1]
    #Red
    low_r = np.array([140,150,0],np.uint8)
    high_r = np.array([180,255,255],np.uint8)

    red=cv2.inRange(hsv,low_r,high_r)
    red = cv2.erode(red, None, iterations=2)
    red = cv2.dilate(red, None, iterations=2)
    
    cnts_r = cv2.findContours(red.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts_r = imutils.grab_contours(cnts_r)
    center_r = None
    if len(cnts_r) > 0:
        c_r = max(cnts_r, key=cv2.contourArea)
        # epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c,True)
        # approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,epsilon,True)
        M_r= cv2.moments(c_r)
        center_r= (int(M_r["m10"] / M_r["m00"]), int(M_r["m01"] / M_r["m00"]))
        cv2.circle(frame, center_r, 5, (255, 255,255), -1)
        xypoints[4]=center_r[0]
        xypoints[5]=center_r[1]

    #Green
    low_g = np.array([40,50,50])
    high_g = np.array([80,255,255])
    #GREEN_DETECTION
    #compute mask, erode and dilate it to remove noise
    green = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_g, high_g)
    green = cv2.erode(green, None, iterations=2)
    green = cv2.dilate(green, None, iterations=2)
    cnts_g = cv2.findContours(green.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts_g = imutils.grab_contours(cnts_g)
    center_g = None
    if len(cnts_g) > 0:
        c_g = max(cnts_g, key=cv2.contourArea)
        # epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(c,True)
        # approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,epsilon,True)
        M_g= cv2.moments(c_g)
        center_g= (int(M_g["m10"] / M_g["m00"]), int(M_g["m01"] / M_g["m00"]))
        cv2.circle(frame, center_g, 5, (255, 255,255), -1)
        xypoints[0]=center_g[0]
        xypoints[1]=center_g[1]
        cv2.circle(frame, (320,240), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
    
   

    
           
    
    cv2.imshow("Color Tracking",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    
    return xypoints

    
def f_points(dimg, xy): 
    fl=531.1   
    zr=dimg[xy[5]][xy[4]]
    zb=dimg[xy[3]][xy[2]]    
    zg=dimg[xy[1]][xy[0]]
    
    
    fpoint=[xy[0], xy[1], zr, xy[2], xy[3], zb, xy[4], xy[5],zg]  
    for i in range(0,len(fpoint),3):
        
        fpoint[i] = (fpoint[i]-320)/(fl/640)
    for j in range(1,len(fpoint),3):
        fpoint[j] = -(fpoint[j]-240)/(fl/480)
    
    return fpoint
 
def main():
    global rgb_img
    global depth_img
    
    rospy.init_node('d_points', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/image_raw', Image, rgb_callback )
    rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/image_raw', Image, d_callback)
    pub=rospy.Publisher('3_point_features', floatList, queue_size=1)
      
    rate=rospy.Rate(10) # in Hz
    features=floatList()
       
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
         
        xy=xy_points(rgb_img)
        
        c=0
        while c<20:
            xy=xy+xy_points(rgb_img)
            c+=1
        
        xy=xy/c
        
        
               
        features.data=f_points(depth_img, xy)
        print(features.data)
        pub.publish(features)
        rate.sleep()
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

CODE FOR VISUAL SERVOING:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from ur5_control_nodes.msg import floatList
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
import numpy as np
from math import *
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from control_msgs.msg import *
from trajectory_msgs.msg import *


joint_positions=None
coordinates=None
c=0
def position_callback(position):
    global joint_positions
    joint_positions=position.position
    


def coordinate_callback(data):
    global coordinates
    coordinates=data.data



def joint_velocities(pose,points):
    
    
    
    if pose!=None:
        if points!=None:
            
            
            theta_x = -pi/2
            theta_y = pi/2
            check=np.array([True,True])
            
            int_matrix = None
            fl = 531.15
            desired_points = [209.67802673696102, -22.59461495010356, 878, 53.022029749576355, 80.43682922236867, 891, 237.3940877424214, 87.66710600640181, 884]

            desired_points = np.asarray(desired_points)
            points=np.asarray(points)
            pix_vel=[]
        
            for index in range(len(points)):
                if (index+1)%3==0:
                    index+=1
                else:
                    pix_vel.append(points[index]-desired_points[index])
            # print pix_vel
            pix_vel=np.asarray(pix_vel) #1v8 array
            pix_vel=np.matrix(pix_vel)
            pix_vel=np.ndarray.transpose(pix_vel)
            

            for i in range(0,len(points),3):
                u = desired_points[i]
                v = desired_points[i+1]
                z = desired_points[i+2]
                # new_mat=np.array([[ -fl/z, 0, u/z, u*v/fl, -(fl*fl+u*u)/fl, v],[ 0, -fl/z, v/z, (fl*fl+v*v)/fl, -u*v/fl, -u ]])
                # new_mat=np.array([[ 0, 0, 0,0,0,0],[ 0, -fl/z, 0, 0,0,0 ]])
                new_mat=np.array([[ -fl/z, 0, u/z, 0,0,0],[ 0, -fl/z, v/z, 0,0,0 ]])
                if i==0:
                    int_matrix=new_mat
                else:
                    int_matrix=np.concatenate((int_matrix,new_mat))
            
            
            
            int_matrix=np.matrix(int_matrix) #8v6 matrix
            inverse=np.linalg.pinv(int_matrix) #6v8 matrix
            
            cam_vel_np=-0.00005*inverse*pix_vel #6v1 matrix
            
            
            cam_vel_lin = cam_vel_np[[0,1,2],:]
            cam_vel_angular = cam_vel_np[[3,4,5],:]
            

            
            
            Rx=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,cos(theta_x),-sin(theta_x)],[0,sin(theta_x),cos(theta_x)]])
            Ry=np.array([[cos(theta_y) , 0, sin(theta_y)],[0, 1, 0],[-sin(theta_y), 0, cos(theta_y)]])
            # Lt=np.array([[1,0,0,-210],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,-85],[0,0,0,1]])
            # # print Rx
            # # print Ry
            # cam_vel_lin=Ry*cam_vel_lin
            # cam_vel_lin=Rx*cam_vel_lin
            
            # cam_vel_lin=np.vstack((cam_vel_lin,[1]))
            
            # cam_vel_lin=Lt*cam_vel_lin
            # cam_vel_lin=np.delete(cam_vel_lin,(3),axis=0)
            
            # cam_vel_angular=Rx*(Ry*cam_vel_angular)
            # cam_vel_angular=np.vstack((cam_vel_angular,[1]))
            # cam_vel_angular=Lt*cam_vel_angular
            # cam_vel_angular=np.delete(cam_vel_angular,(3),axis=0)

            cam_vel_np=np.concatenate((cam_vel_lin,cam_vel_angular))
            # cam_vel_np[2]=-cam_vel_np[2]
            # cam_vel_np[5]=-cam_vel_np[5]
            # cam_vel_np=np.array([[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]])
            # cam_vel_np=np.ndarray.transpose(cam_vel_np)
            # cam_vel_list=np.ndarray.tolist(cam_vel_np)
            # cam_vel_final=cam_vel_list[0]
            temp1 = cam_vel_np.item((0,0))
            temp2 = cam_vel_np.item((1,0))
            temp3 = cam_vel_np.item((2,0))
            temp4 = cam_vel_np.item((3,0))
            temp5 = cam_vel_np.item((4,0))
            temp6 = cam_vel_np.item((5,0))
            # cam_vel_np[0,0] = temp3
            # cam_vel_np[1,0] = -temp1
            # cam_vel_np[2,0] = temp2
            # cam_vel_np[3,0] = temp6
            # cam_vel_np[4,0] = -temp4
            # cam_vel_np[5,0] = temp5
            cam_vel_np[0,0] = temp3
            cam_vel_np[1,0] = -temp1
            cam_vel_np[2,0] = temp2
            cam_vel_np[3,0] = temp6
            cam_vel_np[4,0] = -temp4
            cam_vel_np[5,0] = temp5
        
            
            print cam_vel_np
            
            
            
            Q1=pose[0]
            Q2=pose[1]
            Q3=pose[2]
            Q4=pose[3]
            Q5=pose[4]
            Q6=pose[5]
            jacobian=np.array([[ (2183*np.cos(Q1))/20000 + (823*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q5))/10000 + (17*np.cos(Q2)*np.sin(Q1))/40 - (1569*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q2)*np.sin(Q3))/4000 + (823*np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q5))/10000 - (591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3)*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q4))/6250 - (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q4)*np.sin(Q1))/6250 + (1569*np.cos(Q2)*np.cos(Q3)*np.sin(Q1))/4000, np.cos(Q1)*((1569*np.sin(Q2 + Q3))/4000 + (17*np.sin(Q2))/40 + np.sin(Q5)*((823*np.cos(Q2 + Q3)*np.sin(Q4))/10000 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q4))/10000) + (591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q4))/6250 - (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3)*np.sin(Q4))/6250),                         np.cos(Q1)*((591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 + (1569*np.sin(Q2 + Q3))/4000 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q5))/10000),                         np.cos(Q1)*((591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q5))/10000), (823*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q2)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q3)*np.sin(Q4))/10000 - (823*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q2)*np.cos(Q3)*np.cos(Q4)*np.cos(Q5))/10000 - (823*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q5))/10000 + (823*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q3)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q2)*np.sin(Q4))/10000 + (823*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q4)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q2)*np.sin(Q3))/10000, 0],[ (2183*np.sin(Q1))/20000 - (17*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q2))/40 + (823*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q1))/10000 - (823*np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.cos(Q1)*np.sin(Q5))/10000 + (591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q1)*np.sin(Q4))/6250 + (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q4))/6250 - (1569*np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q2)*np.cos(Q3))/4000 + (1569*np.cos(Q1)*np.sin(Q2)*np.sin(Q3))/4000, np.sin(Q1)*((1569*np.sin(Q2 + Q3))/4000 + (17*np.sin(Q2))/40 + np.sin(Q5)*((823*np.cos(Q2 + Q3)*np.sin(Q4))/10000 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q4))/10000) + (591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3)*np.cos(Q4))/6250 - (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3)*np.sin(Q4))/6250),                         np.sin(Q1)*((591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 + (1569*np.sin(Q2 + Q3))/4000 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q5))/10000),                         np.sin(Q1)*((591*np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q5))/10000), (823*np.cos(Q1)*np.sin(Q5))/10000 - (823*np.cos(Q2)*np.cos(Q3)*np.cos(Q4)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q1))/10000 + (823*np.cos(Q2)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q3)*np.sin(Q4))/10000 + (823*np.cos(Q3)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q2)*np.sin(Q4))/10000 + (823*np.cos(Q4)*np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q2)*np.sin(Q3))/10000,                      0],[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0,                                                      (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 - (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5))/20000 - (1569*np.cos(Q2 + Q3))/4000 - (17*np.cos(Q2))/40 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 - Q5))/20000, (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 - (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5))/20000 - (1569*np.cos(Q2 + Q3))/4000 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 - Q5))/20000, (591*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4))/6250 - (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5))/20000 + (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 - Q5))/20000,                                                                                                                                                                           - (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5))/20000 - (823*np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4 - Q5))/20000,                                                     0],[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0,                                                                                                                                                                                                  np.sin(Q1),                                                                                                                           np.sin(Q1),                                                                                                np.sin(Q1),                                                                                                                                                                                                                           np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.cos(Q1),   np.cos(Q5)*np.sin(Q1) - np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.cos(Q1)*np.sin(Q5)],[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0,                                                                                                                                                                                                 -np.cos(Q1),                                                                                                                          -np.cos(Q1),                                                                                               -np.cos(Q1),                                                                                                                                                                                                                           np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q1), - np.cos(Q1)*np.cos(Q5) - np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q1)*np.sin(Q5)],[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1,                                                                                                                                                                                                        0,                                                                                                                                 0,                                                                                                      0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -np.cos(Q2 + Q3 + Q4),                            -np.sin(Q2 + Q3 + Q4)*np.sin(Q5)]])
            jacobian=np.matrix(jacobian)
            jacobian=np.linalg.pinv(jacobian)
            joint_vel=jacobian*cam_vel_np
            joint_vel=joint_vel
            joint_vel=np.ndarray.transpose(joint_vel)

            
            joint_vel=joint_vel.tolist()
            joint_vel=joint_vel[0]
            joint_vel=tuple(joint_vel)
            print "Joint Velocity: "
            print joint_vel
            
            
            

            
            
            #Creating the publisher
            cam_pub=rospy.Publisher('ur5_joint_velocities',floatList,queue_size=1)
            new_List=floatList()
            new_List.data=joint_vel
            # print new_List
            rate = rospy.Rate(0.5) #20 Hz
            cam_pub.publish(new_List) 
            rate.sleep()
            # print pix_vel

def vs_ur5():
    global joint_positions
    global coordinates
    rospy.init_node('vs_ur5')
    rospy.Subscriber('/3_point_features', floatList,coordinate_callback,queue_size=1)
    rospy.Subscriber("/joint_states", JointState, position_callback,queue_size=1)
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        joint_velocities(joint_positions,coordinates)


  

    




if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        vs_ur5()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

CODE FOR RUNNING THE ROBOT

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import rospy
    from ur5_control_nodes.msg import floatList
    from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
    import numpy as np
    from math import *
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
    from control_msgs.msg import *
    from trajectory_msgs.msg import *


    joint_vel=None   
    JOINT_NAMES=['shoulder_pan_joint', 'shoulder_lift_joint', 'elbow_joint','wrist_1_joint', 'wrist_2_joint', 'wrist_3_joint']
    def joint_velocity_callback(data):
        global joint_vel
        joint_vel = data.data
        
        
        
    def joint_states(velocity):
        global JOINT_NAMES
        
        
        
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/ur_driver/joint_speed', JointTrajectory, queue_size=1)
        
        hello_str = JointTrajectory()
        hello_str.header = Header()
        hello_str.joint_names=JOINT_NAMES
        hello_str.points=[JointTrajectoryPoint(velocities=velocity, time_from_start=rospy.Duration(0.0)),JointTrajectoryPoint(time_from_start=rospy.Duration(0.0))]
        hello_str.header.seq=hello_str.header.seq+1
        hello_str.header.stamp-rospy.Time.now()
        pub.publish(hello_str)
    def run_ur5():
        global joint_vel
        rospy.init_node('run_ur5', anonymous=True)
        

        rospy.Subscriber("ur5_joint_velocities", floatList, joint_velocity_callback,queue_size=1)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            joint_states(joint_vel)
        


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        
            try:
                run_ur5()
            except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
                pass
```

ROS CONTROL LAUNCH FILE:

YAML FILE

## Settings for ros_control control loop

hardware_control_loop:
loop_hz: 125

## Settings for ros_control hardware interface

hardware_interface:
joints:
- shoulder_pan_joint
- shoulder_lift_joint
- elbow_joint
- wrist_1_joint
- wrist_2_joint
- wrist_3_joint

## Publish all joint states ----------------------------------

joint_state_controller:
type:         joint_state_controller/JointStateController
publish_rate: 125

## Publish wrench ----------------------------------

force_torque_sensor_controller:
type:         force_torque_sensor_controller/ForceTorqueSensorController
publish_rate: 125

## Joint Trajectory Controller - position based -------------------------------

## For detailed explanations of parameter see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller

pos_based_pos_traj_controller:
type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
joints:
- shoulder_pan_joint
- shoulder_lift_joint
- elbow_joint
- wrist_1_joint
- wrist_2_joint
- wrist_3_joint
constraints:
goal_time: 0.6
stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
shoulder_pan_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
shoulder_lift_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
elbow_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
wrist_1_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
wrist_2_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
wrist_3_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
state_publish_rate:  125
action_monitor_rate: 10

## state_publish_rate:  50 # Defaults to 50

## action_monitor_rate: 20 # Defaults to 20

#hold_trajectory_duration: 0 # Defaults to 0.5

## Joint Trajectory Controller - velocity based -------------------------------

## For detailed explanations of parameter see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller

joint_group_vel_controller:
type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
joints:
- shoulder_pan_joint
- shoulder_lift_joint
- elbow_joint
- wrist_1_joint
- wrist_2_joint
- wrist_3_joint
constraints:
goal_time: 0.6
stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
shoulder_pan_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
shoulder_lift_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
elbow_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
wrist_1_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
wrist_2_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
wrist_3_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
state_publish_rate:  125
action_monitor_rate: 10
gains:
#!!These values are useable, but maybe not optimal
shoulder_pan_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
shoulder_lift_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
elbow_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
wrist_1_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
wrist_2_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}
wrist_3_joint: {p: 1.2,  i: 0.0, d: 0.1, i_clamp: 1}

## state_publish_rate:  50 # Defaults to 50

## action_monitor_rate: 20 # Defaults to 20

#hold_trajectory_duration: 0 # Defaults to 0.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325114/ur5+velocity-control:-runaway-robot-after-getting-closer-to-goal-pose/) by [Rik1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/36084/rik1234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reducing the situation to just looking at the lag reported by the OP, he implemented a MWE that just publishes a simple velocity to the `command` topic.

In the MWE we see:

> ```
>   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
> ```

```
        vels=[0,0,0.05,0,0,0]
        pub.publish(vels)
```

this publishes the same velocity at about the maximum rate your computer is able to achieve -- which for typical PCs these days could be 10000 Hz or faster with these small messages.

@Rik1234: you may want to add a sleep in there to moderate the rate at which this loop is executed. There is no point in publishing any faster than the maximum of the URs control loop, which, if you have a non-e-series controller, would be 125 Hz.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rik1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/36084/rik1234/) on 2019-06-11**:
Yes, that was it. Now there is no lag between the robot. However, solving one problem leads to another, and for some reason, my jacobian isn't working anymore. I loaded the previous controller launch file and the jacobian worked differently in both the controllers.I checked the order of the joints in the yaml file, there is no change there. Why is this happening? Even if I can run the code using the old launch, I would like to know the issue behind this. Also, the operations on both the controllers are extremely jerky. Is there a problem with my visual servoing control algorithm?

**Comment by [Rik1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/36084/rik1234/) on 2019-06-12**:
Maybe this will be a separate question. I'll ask in a new thread.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-13**:
I'm not sure why you posted a new question.

Afaik, both the `JointGroupVelocityController` and the old `joint_speed` topic use the exact same interface to the robot controller.

Again, as with your initial problem, reduce everything to the absolute minimum and start debugging from there.

**Comment by [Rik1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/36084/rik1234/) on 2019-06-13**:
I did try that. the joint velocities as well as the end effector velocities are different in both the controllers. I asked in a separate question because the original delay problem was solved, and this was a different issue. I was hoping if someone could take a closer look at the code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-14**:
Just to give this thread some closure, I've restructured the comments into an answer.

Could you accept the answer if you feel we've sufficiently dealt with the lag issue?

**Comment by [Rik1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/36084/rik1234/) on 2019-06-15**:
Sure. I'll do that. Thanks for your help.